# Production company(s?) for "Face Off" and "Ink Masters"

Tags: production, credits

I've been watching SyFy's series "Face Off" [(IMDB)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663641/) since its first season debut. Recently, I watched an episode of SpikeTV's "Ink Master."

I'm not typically a huge fan of 'reality' TV so I was surprised to see how similar these shows were. The format was nearly identical. I was wondering if these two shows were from the same production company, despite being on two separate channels.

If so or not, who is producing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Face Off is a production of Mission Control Media with Michael Agbabian and Dwight D. Smith as exectutive producers (From [SyFi Website Face Off About page](http://www.syfy.com/faceoff/about))

Ink Master is a production of Original Media, with Charlie Corwin, Jay Peterson, and Andrea Richter as executive producers (From press release included on [TV Series Finale website](http://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/ink-master-season-two-22115/)).  Original Media is part of the Endemol reality-tv empire.

It looks like just a coincidence.